# Reverse a graph - trying to get mote efficient

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, coding-efficiency

I'm trying to get more efficient in this reverse graph problem. The idea is straightforward, you get a directed connected cyclic graph and you reverse the direction of the edges.

I got it right, but I'd like to make it faster, some entries are taking almost 2s. That's terrible...

If someone knows anything that can help to speed up this code below, please tell me.

```
static class Node
        {
            Integer val;
            Vector<Node> neighbours = new Vector<Node>(0);
            Node(Integer _val)
            {
                val = _val;
                neighbours.clear();
            }
        };

static Node build_other_graph(Node node)
    {
        if(node.neighbours.size() == 0)
            return new Node(node.val);

        dfs(node);
        return col.get(node.val);
    }

    static Node n = null;
    static HashMap<Integer, Node> col = new HashMap<>();
    static HashSet<Integer> visited = new HashSet<>();
    static void dfs(Node node)
    {
        if(node == null || visited.contains(node.val))
            return;

        //visit
        Vector<Node> adj = node.neighbours;
        visited.add(node.val);
        for(Node i: adj)
        {
            if(col.keySet().contains(i.val))
            {
               if(col.keySet().contains(node.val))
                    col.get(i.val).neighbours.add(col.get(node.val));
               else
                   col.get(i.val).neighbours.add(new Node(node.val));
            }
            else
            {
               Node v = new Node(i.val);
               if(col.keySet().contains(node.val))
                    v.neighbours.add(col.get(node.val));
               else
                    v.neighbours.add(new Node(node.val));
               col.put(i.val, v);
            }
            dfs(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you do not need dfs here, just store all nodes in ArrayList,  add Vector<Node> neighbours_reverse to each node,  then iterate over all nodes while looking what in neighbours are and write current node to neigbours neighbours_reverse list. then you could swap neighbours and  neighbours_reverse. try to do shallow what you can about graphs

Answer (score 0):

So here is simple example of what i mean. See how long it runs - mutch more time for initialisation, but reverse goes instantly and only ones

```
   package graph.nodes.simple;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GArrayListGraph extends ArrayList<GArrayListNode> {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2493196722065921126L;
    boolean calculated = false;



    public GArrayListNode addNode(Object e) {

        GArrayListNode ret = new GArrayListNode(e);
        super.add(ret);
        return ret ;
    }

    public void addEdge(GArrayListNode a, GArrayListNode b) {

        a.neighbours.add(b);
    }   


    public void printall() {

        System.out.println("GArrayListGraph");

        for (GArrayListNode node : this) {


            System.out.println(node.toString());
        }

    }


    public void reverce() {

        if (!calculated) {
            for (GArrayListNode node : this) {

                for (GArrayListNode neighbour : node.neighbours) {

                    neighbour.neighboursReverse.add(node);

                }
            }
            this.calculated = true;
        }
        // swap neighbours and neighboursReverse
        for (GArrayListNode node : this) {

            ArrayList<GArrayListNode> temp = node.neighbours;
            node.neighbours = node.neighboursReverse;
            node.neighboursReverse = temp;

        }

    }
}    



package graph.nodes.simple;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Random;


import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class GArrayListNode {

    Object val;
    ArrayList<GArrayListNode> neighbours;
    ArrayList<GArrayListNode> neighboursReverse;

    public GArrayListNode(Object val) {
        this.val = val;
        this.neighbours = new ArrayList<GArrayListNode>();
        this.neighboursReverse = new ArrayList<GArrayListNode>();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return val.toString() + " : " + this.toStringChildren();
    }

    public String toStringChildren() {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (GArrayListNode node : neighbours) {

            sb.append(node.val).append(',');

        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GArrayListGraph g = new GArrayListGraph();

        GArrayListNode n10 = g.addNode(10);

        GArrayListNode n11 = g.addNode(11);

        GArrayListNode n12 = g.addNode(12);

        GArrayListNode n13 = g.addNode(13);

        GArrayListNode n14 = g.addNode(14);

        g.addEdge(n10, n11);

        g.addEdge(n11, n12);

        g.addEdge(n10, n12);

        g.addEdge(n12, n13);

        g.addEdge(n12, n14);

        g.addEdge(n14, n10);

        g.printall();

        g.reverce();

        g.printall();

        g.reverce();

        g.printall();

        System.out.println("see its the same, now time performance test");

        int nodes = 1000 * 1000 * 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes; i++) {

            g.addNode(i);

        }

        int edges = 1000 * 10;

        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes; i++) {

            int from = r.nextInt(nodes);
            int to = r.nextInt(nodes);

            g.addEdge(g.get(from), g.get(to));


        }

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("start" );
        g.reverce();

        long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

        System.out.println("elapsed " + elapsed);



    }

}
```